# Sorted for-each loop in XSLT can not reference nodes to XPath query outside of loop

Tags: for-loop, xslt-2.0

I am attempting to loop through a set of nodes to build a menu of distinct, sorted values.  All the possible values are known, but which and how many are included in the XML is not known at run time.  The known list changes from time to time, so including the full list would require maintenance control I would rather avoid.

The error text is **Required item type of the context item for the parent axis is node(); supplied value has item type xs:anyAtomicType**.

I am using XSLT 2.0 from Xerces embedded in Solr 7.6.

I think I understand why, because I am contextually at a text value and not at a node, but I do not know a way around it.

Here is an example XML...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<response>

<result name="response" numFound="25" start="0">
  <doc>
    <str name="id">REF-50102</str>
    <str name="type-name">Reference</str>
    <str name="type-abbrv">REF</str>
  </doc>
  <doc>
    <str name="id">REF-50222</str>
    <str name="type-name">Reference</str>
    <str name="type-abbrv">REF</str>
  </doc>
  <doc>
    <str name="id">REF-50245</str>
    <str name="type-name">Reference</str>
    <str name="type-abbrv">REF</str>
  </doc>
  <doc>
    <str name="id">REF-50029</str>
    <str name="type-name">Reference</str>
    <str name="type-abbrv">REF</str>
  </doc>
  <doc>
    <str name="id">SUB-4</str>
    <str name="type-name">Subsystem</str>
    <str name="type-abbrv">SUB</str>
    <str name="system-name">AC-9</str>
  </doc>
  <doc>
    <str name="id">STK-80</str>
    <str name="type-name">Stack</str>
    <str name="type-abbrv">STK</str>
    <str name="system-name">AC-9</str>
  </doc>
  <doc>
    <str name="id">STK-61</str>
    <str name="type-name">Stack</str>
    <str name="type-abbrv">STK</str>
    <str name="system-name">AC-9</str>
  </doc>
  <doc>
    <str name="id">FLM-50025</str>
    <str name="type-name">Flavor</str>
    <str name="type-abbrv">FLM</str>
    <str name="system-name">AC-9</str>
  </doc>
  <doc>
    <str name="id">FLM-50108</str>
    <str name="type-name">Flavor</str>
    <str name="type-abbrv">FLM</str>
    <str name="system-name">AC-9</str>
  </doc>
  <doc>
    <str name="id">FLM-50109</str>
    <str name="type-name">Flavor</str>
    <str name="type-abbrv">FLM</str>
    <str name="system-name">AC-9</str>
  </doc>
  <doc>
    <str name="id">PFP-50101</str>
    <str name="type-name">Prefabricated</str>
    <str name="type-abbrv">PFP</str>
    <str name="system-name">AC-9</str>
  </doc>
  <doc>
    <str name="id">PFP-50103</str>
    <str name="type-name">Prefabricated</str>
    <str name="type-abbrv">PFP</str>
    <str name="system-name">AC-9</str>
  </doc>
  <doc>
    <str name="id">DSG-50163</str>
    <str name="type-name">Design Drawing</str>
    <str name="type-abbrv">DSG</str>
    <str name="system-name">AB-4</str>
  </doc>
  <doc>
    <str name="id">DSG-50164</str>
    <str name="type-name">Design Drawing</str>
    <str name="type-abbrv">DSG</str>
    <str name="system-name">AC-8</str>
  </doc>
  <doc>
    <str name="id">DSG-50162</str>
    <str name="type-name">Design Drawing</str>
    <str name="type-abbrv">DSG</str>
    <str name="system-name">AB-4</str>
  </doc>
  <doc>
    <str name="id">PXS-81</str>
    <str name="type-name">Production Assembly</str>
    <str name="type-abbrv">PXS</str>
    <str name="system-name">AC-9</str>
  </doc>
  <doc>
    <str name="id">PXS-83</str>
    <str name="type-name">Production Assembly</str>
    <str name="type-abbrv">PXS</str>
    <str name="system-name">AC-9</str>
  </doc>
  <doc>
    <str name="id">PXS-82</str>
    <str name="type-name">Production Assembly</str>
    <str name="type-abbrv">PXS</str>
    <str name="system-name">AC-9</str>
  </doc>
  <doc>
    <str name="id">DWG-42</str>
    <str name="type-name">Drawing</str>
    <str name="type-abbrv">DWG</str>
    <str name="system-name">AC-9</str>
  </doc>
</result>
</response>
```

And the XSL transform with the errors causing lines are commented out...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    exclude-result-prefixes="xs"
    version="2.0">
    <!-- =========================================================================================== -->
    <xsl:output method="html" indent="yes"/>
    <!-- =========================================================================================== -->
    <xsl:template match="/response">
        <html>
            <head>
            <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
            </head>
            <body>
                <xsl:comment>Working if I know the list, but I do not.</xsl:comment>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="result" mode="countKnownList"/>
                <hr/>
                <xsl:comment>Finds list dynamically, but can not get name or count.</xsl:comment>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="result" mode="countUnknownList"/>
            </body>
        </html>
    </xsl:template>
    <!-- =========================================================================================== -->
    <xsl:template name="listElementUnknownList">
        <xsl:param name="abbrv"/>
        <xsl:param name="name"/>
<!-- What I have tried unsuccessfully.
        <xsl:variable name="quantity"><xsl:value-of select="count(//doc/str[@name='type-abbrv']/text()='$abbrv')"/></xsl:variable>
 -->
        <xsl:variable name="quantity">#</xsl:variable>
        <li><label>
            <xsl:element name="input">
                <xsl:attribute name="id"><xsl:value-of select="$abbrv"/></xsl:attribute>
                <xsl:attribute name="type">checkbox</xsl:attribute>
                <xsl:attribute name="checked">true</xsl:attribute>
                <xsl:attribute name="onclick">toggleRows('<xsl:value-of select="$abbrv"/>');</xsl:attribute>
            </xsl:element><xsl:value-of select="$name"/>(<xsl:value-of select="$quantity" />)</label></li>
    </xsl:template>
    <!-- =========================================================================================== -->
     <xsl:template match="result" mode="countUnknownList">
        <dl>
            <dt>Type (<xsl:value-of select="count(doc)" />)</dt>
            <dd>
                <ul>
                    <xsl:for-each select="distinct-values(doc/str[@name='type-abbrv'])">
                        <xsl:sort select="."/>
                        <xsl:variable name="typeAbbrv"><xsl:value-of select="."/></xsl:variable>
<!--  What I have tried unsuccessfully.
                        <xsl:variable name="typeName"><xsl:value-of select="../str[@name='type-name']"/></xsl:variable>
 -->
                        <xsl:variable name="typeName"><xsl:value-of select="$typeAbbrv"/>-name</xsl:variable>
                        <xsl:call-template name="listElementUnknownList">
                            <xsl:with-param name="abbrv"><xsl:value-of select="$typeAbbrv"/></xsl:with-param>
                            <xsl:with-param name="name"><xsl:value-of select="$typeName"/></xsl:with-param>
                        </xsl:call-template>
                    </xsl:for-each>
                 </ul>
            </dd>
            <dt>System (<xsl:value-of select="count(doc)" />)</dt>
            <dd>
                <ul>
                    <xsl:for-each select="distinct-values(doc/str[@name='system-name']/text())">
                        <xsl:sort select="."/>
                        <xsl:variable name="sysName"><xsl:value-of select="."/></xsl:variable>
                        <xsl:call-template name="listElementUnknownList">
                            <xsl:with-param name="abbrv"><xsl:value-of select="$sysName"/></xsl:with-param>
                            <xsl:with-param name="name"><xsl:value-of select="$sysName"/></xsl:with-param>
                        </xsl:call-template>
                    </xsl:for-each>
                    <xsl:call-template name="listElementUnknownList">
                        <xsl:with-param name="abbrv">None</xsl:with-param>
                        <xsl:with-param name="name">None</xsl:with-param>
                    </xsl:call-template>
                </ul>
            </dd>
        </dl>
    </xsl:template>
    <!-- =========================================================================================== -->
    <xsl:template name="listElementKnownList">
        <xsl:param name="abbrv"/>
        <xsl:param name="name"/>
        <xsl:param name="quantity"/>
        <li><label>
            <xsl:element name="input">
                <xsl:attribute name="id"><xsl:value-of select="$abbrv"/></xsl:attribute>
                <xsl:attribute name="type">checkbox</xsl:attribute>
                <xsl:attribute name="checked">true</xsl:attribute>
                <xsl:attribute name="onclick">toggleRows('<xsl:value-of select="$abbrv"/>');</xsl:attribute>
            </xsl:element><xsl:value-of select="$name"/>(<xsl:value-of select="$quantity" />)</label></li>
    </xsl:template>
    <!-- =========================================================================================== -->
     <xsl:template match="result" mode="countKnownList">
        <dl>
            <dt>Type (<xsl:value-of select="count(doc)" />)</dt>
            <dd>
                <ul>
                    <xsl:call-template name="listElementKnownList">
                        <xsl:with-param name="abbrv">DSG</xsl:with-param>
                        <xsl:with-param name="name">Design Drawing</xsl:with-param>
                        <xsl:with-param name="quantity"><xsl:value-of select="count(doc[str[@name='type-abbrv']/text()='DSG'])"/></xsl:with-param>
                    </xsl:call-template>
                    <xsl:call-template name="listElementKnownList">
                        <xsl:with-param name="abbrv">FLM</xsl:with-param>
                        <xsl:with-param name="name">Flavor</xsl:with-param>
                        <xsl:with-param name="quantity"><xsl:value-of select="count(doc[str[@name='type-abbrv']/text()='FLM'])"/></xsl:with-param>
                    </xsl:call-template>
                    <xsl:call-template name="listElementKnownList">
                        <xsl:with-param name="abbrv">STK</xsl:with-param>
                        <xsl:with-param name="name">Stack</xsl:with-param>
                        <xsl:with-param name="quantity"><xsl:value-of select="count(doc[str[@name='type-abbrv']/text()='STK'])"/></xsl:with-param>
                    </xsl:call-template>
                    <!-- etc -->
                </ul>
            </dd>
        </dl>
    </xsl:template>
    <!-- =========================================================================================== -->
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

And finally, the result with the placeholders for unavailable data...

```
<html>
   <head>
      <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
   </head>
   <body>
      <!--Working if I know the list, but I do not.-->
      <dl>
         <dt>Type (19)</dt>
         <dd>
            <ul>
               <li><label><input id="DSG" type="checkbox" checked="true" onclick="toggleRows('DSG');">Design Drawing(3)</label></li>
               <li><label><input id="FLM" type="checkbox" checked="true" onclick="toggleRows('FLM');">Flavor(3)</label></li>
               <li><label><input id="STK" type="checkbox" checked="true" onclick="toggleRows('STK');">Stack(2)</label></li>
            </ul>
         </dd>
      </dl>
      <hr>
      <!--Finds list dynamically, but can not get name or count.-->
      <dl>
         <dt>Type (19)</dt>
         <dd>
            <ul>
               <li><label><input id="DSG" type="checkbox" checked="true" onclick="toggleRows('DSG');">DSG-name(#)</label></li>
               <li><label><input id="DWG" type="checkbox" checked="true" onclick="toggleRows('DWG');">DWG-name(#)</label></li>
               <li><label><input id="FLM" type="checkbox" checked="true" onclick="toggleRows('FLM');">FLM-name(#)</label></li>
               <li><label><input id="PFP" type="checkbox" checked="true" onclick="toggleRows('PFP');">PFP-name(#)</label></li>
               <li><label><input id="PXS" type="checkbox" checked="true" onclick="toggleRows('PXS');">PXS-name(#)</label></li>
               <li><label><input id="REF" type="checkbox" checked="true" onclick="toggleRows('REF');">REF-name(#)</label></li>
               <li><label><input id="STK" type="checkbox" checked="true" onclick="toggleRows('STK');">STK-name(#)</label></li>
               <li><label><input id="SUB" type="checkbox" checked="true" onclick="toggleRows('SUB');">SUB-name(#)</label></li>
            </ul>
         </dd>
         <dt>System (19)</dt>
         <dd>
            <ul>
               <li><label><input id="AB-4" type="checkbox" checked="true" onclick="toggleRows('AB-4');">AB-4(#)</label></li>
               <li><label><input id="AC-8" type="checkbox" checked="true" onclick="toggleRows('AC-8');">AC-8(#)</label></li>
               <li><label><input id="AC-9" type="checkbox" checked="true" onclick="toggleRows('AC-9');">AC-9(#)</label></li>
               <li><label><input id="None" type="checkbox" checked="true" onclick="toggleRows('None');">None(#)</label></li>
            </ul>
         </dd>
      </dl>
   </body>
</html
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The variable solves your problem but you wouldn't have it if you just used `xsl:for-each-group` e.g.

```
   <xsl:for-each-group select="doc" group-by="str[@name='type-abbrv']">
                    <xsl:sort select="current-grouping-key()"/>
                    <xsl:variable name="typeAbbrv" select="current-grouping-key()"/>

                    <xsl:variable name="typeName" select="str[@name='type-name']"/>

                    <xsl:variable name="typeName"><xsl:value-of select="$typeAbbrv"/>-name</xsl:variable>
                    <xsl:call-template name="listElementUnknownList">
                        <xsl:with-param name="abbrv"><xsl:value-of select="$typeAbbrv"/></xsl:with-param>
                        <xsl:with-param name="name"><xsl:value-of select="$typeName"/></xsl:with-param>
                    </xsl:call-template>
   </xsl:for-each-group>
```

which of course can be shortened to

```
   <xsl:for-each-group select="doc" group-by="str[@name='type-abbrv']">
                    <xsl:sort select="current-grouping-key()"/>
                    <xsl:call-template name="listElementUnknownList">
                        <xsl:with-param name="abbrv" select="current-grouping-key()"/>
                        <xsl:with-param name="name" select="concat(str[@name='type-name'], '-name')"/>
                    </xsl:call-template>
   </xsl:for-each-group>
```

So I think grouping is what you really want, I have tried to implement part of that as

```
 <xsl:template match="result" mode="countUnknownList">
    <dl>
        <dt>Type (<xsl:value-of select="count(doc)" />)</dt>
        <dd>
            <ul>
               <xsl:for-each-group select="doc" group-by="str[@name='type-abbrv']">
                    <xsl:sort select="current-grouping-key()"/>
                    <li>
                       <label>
                           <input id="{current-grouping-key()}"
                                  type="checkbox"
                                  checked="checked"
                                  onclick="toggleRows('{current-grouping-key()}');"/>
                            <xsl:value-of select="concat(str[@name='type-name'], '(', count(current-group()), ')')"/>

                       </label> 
                    </li>
               </xsl:for-each-group>
             </ul>
        </dd>
        <dt>System (<xsl:value-of select="count(doc)" />)</dt>
        <dd>
            <ul>
               <xsl:for-each-group select="doc" group-by="str[@name='system-name']">
                    <xsl:sort select="current-grouping-key()"/>
                    <li>
                       <label>
                           <input id="{current-grouping-key()}"
                                  type="checkbox"
                                  checked="checked"
                                  onclick="toggleRows('{current-grouping-key()}');"/>
                            <xsl:value-of select="concat(current-grouping-key(), '(', count(current-group()), ')')"/>

                       </label> 
                    </li>
               </xsl:for-each-group>                    
            </ul>
        </dd>
    </dl>
</xsl:template>
```

at https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/gWvjQf4, result for your sample there is one list

```
        <ul>
           <li><label><input id="DSG" type="checkbox" checked onclick="toggleRows('DSG');">Design Drawing(3)</label></li>
           <li><label><input id="DWG" type="checkbox" checked onclick="toggleRows('DWG');">Drawing(1)</label></li>
           <li><label><input id="FLM" type="checkbox" checked onclick="toggleRows('FLM');">Flavor(3)</label></li>
           <li><label><input id="PFP" type="checkbox" checked onclick="toggleRows('PFP');">Prefabricated(2)</label></li>
           <li><label><input id="PXS" type="checkbox" checked onclick="toggleRows('PXS');">Production Assembly(3)</label></li>
           <li><label><input id="REF" type="checkbox" checked onclick="toggleRows('REF');">Reference(4)</label></li>
           <li><label><input id="STK" type="checkbox" checked onclick="toggleRows('STK');">Stack(2)</label></li>
           <li><label><input id="SUB" type="checkbox" checked onclick="toggleRows('SUB');">Subsystem(1)</label></li>
        </ul>
```

and the second as

```
        <ul>
           <li><label><input id="AB-4" type="checkbox" checked onclick="toggleRows('AB-4');">AB-4(2)</label></li>
           <li><label><input id="AC-8" type="checkbox" checked onclick="toggleRows('AC-8');">AC-8(1)</label></li>
           <li><label><input id="AC-9" type="checkbox" checked onclick="toggleRows('AC-9');">AC-9(12)</label></li>
        </ul>
```

hope I have grasped what the original code intended to do.

Comment: Nice solution without the global variable.  I prefer your solution.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

One way to circumvent this is by defining a top-level variable containing the whole document like in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19679521/1305969):

```
...
<xsl:output method="html" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:variable name="mainDoc" select="/" />
...
```

Then reference it in your commented-out variables (I also changed the predicate in the `count` to count the desired nodes):

The first

```
<xsl:variable name="quantity" select="count($mainDoc/response/result/doc/str[@name='type-abbrv' and text()=$abbrv])"/>
```

and the second

```
<xsl:variable name="typeName" select="($mainDoc//doc[str[@name='type-abbrv']/text()=$typeAbbrv]/str[@name='type-name'])[1]" />
```

Comment: Your solution works, and I originally selected it, but Martin's solution below uses a "cleaner" implementation without having to declare the global variable.